# PHP - When error display 404 AND Show errors for webmaster on seperate page?

Tags: php, redirect

This is a curiosity of mine that I thought of last night.
Commonly when I am updating my PHP on a website I will reach an error from missing a letter or symbol correctly. If this is done while editing a live site the visitors may see the errors.

So here is an idea, that I have not found once on Google and I am hoping it is possible.

Let's say I screw up a line of code in a 3000 line site that is live.

Is it possible to tell the site via PHP that if there is an error to redirect all site visitors to a "Error 404" page or "Maintenance" page but on the other side display errors on a custom page that only the webmaster sees?

Basically like this.

My site reaches an error.

Site visitors are redirected to: http://example.com/maintenance.php
And for me to see the actual error I visit http://example.com/webmasterError.php?

I know that it is possible to have your errors e-mailed to you, but this is moreover an experiment that I may implement later, OR someone else may implement if they find it useful.

If I am not mistaken ErrorDocument 500 /500.html can make the redirection to the maintenance page, but what about displaying the errors on a specific page?

That is where I am stuck.

Thanks all. I realize this probably sounds like an idea a beginner would come up with, but I believe it could be useful sometimes.

**EDIT**

Some users have mentioned using localhost for editing so that errors only happen locally. I cannot disagree with this, but to add to other possibilities of using this, let's just hypothetically say that you are using PHP to include an external file from another site. Like if your getting user info from the Facebook graph API and Facebook decides to take away the page you are trying to access. Your site possibly may display an error stating that the stream could not be opened. This would be happening on your live site.

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible. You'd have to store the error information somewhere that webmasterError.php then reads from. Though, what happens if the error that is occurring also causes webmasterError.php to fail?

Comment: It sounds like a good idea to protect visitors from errors on your site. But you should really edit you website first on a local testing server and when you are done editing and know it's error free you should upload it to the public server.

Comment: That is a good question actually. I'm sure that if I were to use two seperate codes for the main site and the webmasterError.php then if one code failed then the other shouldn't. I guess it would just come down to trying it out and seeing how it goes.

Comment: Mark I cannot disagree with that, but this is more of a hypothetical question just in case I wanted to use it on a live site or someone else since I have yet to come across any results on the web for doing something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about PHP log, like when you are starting some infinite loops, or error catch with a try-catch structure ?

Because you could do it in differents way :

Do 2 pages, a simple 404, for visitors, or a special one, which read a mysql table storing all non solved errors.

OR

connect to your site, but having a special "admin account", and on the same 404 as the user, add error logs.

Comment: No. I'm talking an actual page that displays the error. When my code has an error it displays an error box on the page with the error code, what line it is on, which file, etc. and I was hoping there was a way to display those error codes on an entirely separate page than what the visitor shows.

Comment: Oh ok. So you'll need to disable error display (apache config), then in your special PHP page, do a little function which will read apache log file, and display it.

Comment: Interesting solution. I will have to look into doing that.

Answer (score 0):

So I've been working on this. I now have my errors going to a log file which I am going to display on a seperate page. I have ran into an issue though. When testing how my errors are handled I simply remove a ";" from one of my arrays to force an error. When this happen my entire site goes down. This is not expected. I do expect the site to go down, but I also expect it to display some type of message based off of my .htaccess file.

```
ErrorDocument 400 "<p>Error 500</p><p>This Page Is Down For Maintenance.</p>"
ErrorDocument 401 "<p>Error 401</p><p>Authorization Required.</p>"
ErrorDocument 403 "<p>Error 403</p><p>Forbidden.</p>"
ErrorDocument 404 "<p>Error 404</p><p>Not Found.</p>"
ErrorDocument 500 "<p>Error 500</p><p>Internal Server Error.</p>"

# supress php errors
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off

# enable PHP error logging
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  PHP_errors.log
```

I was thinking that the Error 500 warning would show up when the code fails but instead I get a fully blank page.

My 404 error works perfectly fine though so I know my .htaccess file is being read by the server correctly.